# can't seem to install mongoose for node js module

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

hello I am trying to install mongoose into my program, I have required it and when I try using npm install it seems to hit an error so can anyone please help me out on what should be done

error message:

```
 Error: EACCES, unlink '"my path"/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink 'my path"/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '"my path"/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp' }
npm ERR!
```

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator" ...

Comment: I am trying to run without giving the root/administrator, it shout work without it right?